# How do I insert or create data with Django ORM programmatically? Or how do I specific Model field name with a string?

Tags: django, django-models

If I have:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

config = {
        "data": 1,
        "field": "number"
}
```

How do I do the following?

```
record = Tag(config["field"]=config["data"])
record.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack dict to arguments using this syntax `**`. For example:

```
config = {
    "number": 1
}
record = Tag(**config)
record.save()
```

This will create new tag instance with `number=1` value.